# Cannot compare results of a method to a "T" key java

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

```
import java.util.*;
public class Searcher<T> {
    // Returns the index of the key in the sorted array, or -1 if the 
    // key is not found.
    public static <T> int binarySearch(T[] array, int arraySize, T key, 
            Comparator<T> comparer) {
               
        int lowBound = 0; 
        int highBound = arraySize - 1;
        int mid = 0;
        //string this.key = key;
        while (highBound > lowBound) {
           mid = (highBound - lowBound) / 2;
           String results = comparer.compare(array[mid], key.toString());
         
           if(results > key){
              lowBound = mid + 1; 
           }
           else if(results > key) {
              highBound = mid - 1;
           }
           else { return mid;
           }
        }
        
        return -1;
    }
}
```

when i run the program I get this error:

```
Searcher.java:17: error: bad operand types for binary operator '<'
           if(results < key){
                      ^
  first type:  int
  second type: T
  where T is a type-variable:
```

For both lines 17 and 20. i cannot for the  life of me figure out how to compare the results from line 15 to the key i am searching for in my binary search algorithm.][2]

Comment: Please post the code as text. You can use Ctrl-K or the {} button in the rich editor toolbar.

Comment: you can have T implement the Comparable interface, then rather than using > or < you use compareTo; bearing in mind that compareTo returns an int and depending on how you compare objects of type T you will need to cater accordingly; i also just saw result is of type String, so you may want to review this and consistently use type T

Comment: @Ryan Hurling how would that look? results.compareTo(key)? sorry i am just learning java for college so very new.

Comment: See (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-). Comparator.compare takes two parameters of type T, but you are giving it a T and a String. Your current code does not compile as variable key is not declared (it was commented out). Then you are trying to use > operator on results, which is a String. To compare string, you have to use String.compareTo() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of Comparator::compare is an int, as such you need to change result to be of type int and not String, then you can correct the if else as shown below. a result of 1 indicates that your value is large, 0 is the same, and -1 is less (this depends on how you have implemented the comparator.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Searcher<T> {
// Returns the index of the key in the sorted array, or -1 if the 
// key is not found.
public static <T> int binarySearch(T[] array, int arraySize, T key, 
        Comparator<T> comparer) {
           
    int lowBound = 0; 
    int highBound = arraySize - 1;
    int mid = 0;
    //string this.key = key;
    while (highBound > lowBound) {
       mid = (highBound - lowBound) / 2;
       int results = comparer.compare(array[mid], key);
     
       if(results > 0){
          lowBound = mid + 1; 
       }
       else if(results < 0) {
          highBound = mid - 1;
       }
       else { return mid;
       }
    }
    
    return -1;
}
}
```

As mentioned in my comment you can have type T implement comparable and then use the Comparable::compareTo method; this would remove the requirement for the Comparator in the method signature.

Example:

```
public class Searcher<T extends Comparable<T>> {
// Returns the index of the key in the sorted array, or -1 if the
// key is not found.
public int binarySearch(T[] array, int arraySize, T key) {

    int lowBound = 0;
    int highBound = arraySize - 1;
    int mid = 0;
    //string this.key = key;
    while (highBound > lowBound) {
       mid = (highBound - lowBound) / 2;
       int results = key.compareTo(array[mid]);

       if(results > 0){
          lowBound = mid + 1;
       }
       else if(results < 0) {
          highBound = mid - 1;
       }
       else { return mid;
       }
    }

    return -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: it has to be sent through the Comparer for the question to be graded. This does run on eclipes but doesnt run on Zybooks unfortunately. ill have to see why from my instructor.

Comment: in that case, use the first option; however, I would keep in mind that (IMO) that is the least optimal solution, the second example enforces the user of your Searcher to define the logic on how to compare two objects of type T and simplifies the method signature. you can further simplify it by removing the arraySize parameter as you can obtain this from the passed in array.

Comment: thank you very much for the help! and i wish i could use the easier solution

Comment: not a problem, I know how colleges can be with requiring certain signatures for coding questions, if the question is answered please mark the answer :). thanks,